# Does SMS Retriever API is required in Firebase authentication for otp auto fill?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-permissions

I am using `Firebase auth api` to verify user phone number. Currently in my case I have one screen where user put phone number and on second screen otp. As per documentation `firebase` automatic retrieve otp and start verification process most of time. 
So my question is it already implemented this `SMS Retriever API` in Firebase Auth SDK or Should I implement it myself to retrieve SMS and auto fill OTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. we don't need to manage SMS-retrival scenario.

If device contains same SIM-card, It's automatically managed by `PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks` in `onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential)` method.

**Snippet:**

```
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            Toast.makeText(FCMsmsTest.this, "onVerificationCompleted " + phoneAuthCredential.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(FCMsmsTest.this, "onVerificationFailed " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                Toast.makeText(FCMsmsTest.this, "Invalid Request " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Toast.makeText(FCMsmsTest.this, "The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            Toast.makeText(FCMsmsTest.this, "onCodeSent " + verificationId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editText.setText("");

            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken = token;

            showDialog();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you refer any official doc for this ?

Comment: [This doc.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) does the work. we just need code to implement. What issue are you facing with using it?

Comment: as doc says I got my answer 
`// This callback will be invoked in two situations:
        // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
        //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
        // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
        //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
        //     user action.`

Comment: Thanks @Rumit Patel

Comment: My Pleasure @Rakesh that my suggestion helped you. happy coding :-)

Comment: What if the phone doesn't have auto verification using google play services, can we use SMS Retriever API to do that ourselves?

Comment: @RussWheeler, IFAIK it's not seems to possible. and I guess almost every phone are having `google-play-services.` could you please tell for which device you need it?

Comment: I tried it on my friends Huawei and it didn't auto detect the sms code and sign him in. It also says "On some devices Google Play services can automatically" some does not mean all! :D