# Phone Auth auto verification not working in Flutter Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase's phone auth in a flutter app. Everything works fine but auto verification of OTP is not working. User has to manually input the OTP. Looking on the web, it seemed like APP_NAME in `%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.` must be shorter for it to work.

Currently, it is `<my_project_id>.firebaseapp.com`. I have enabled Device Verification on GCP and followed all the steps in the documentation. I have also published the app on playstore under internal testing and it has been reviewed but APP_NAME has still not updated.

What do I need to update this and is it going to make OTP auto-verification work?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is similar to the one listed below, without additional details (IE: code examples) there is no way to have a definite solution.

But based on the limited information provided, you have to ensure that you have the `setCallbacks` setup with your `OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks`  handler as indicated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone).

Another thing to note is this can be automatically done in two ways

> This callback will be invoked in two situations:
>
> 1 - Instant verification. In some cases, the phone number can be instantly verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
>
> 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices, Google Play services can automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user action.

So ensure that the `Google Play` service is running on the device to allow this to occur. (Note the *"On some devices"*)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809370/5779200